# unable to run a JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

Every time I try to run my application I am getting this error message : "Error: Unable to initialize main class TipCalculator" Can You please assist?

I am using Visual Studio Code as editor and I am trying to sun in the editor.

When I use the command prompt I get this error: Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 > -2

I tried adding dependencies but I don't know how to and there is no proper flow for it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the getting started documentation at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).